# How to tell raspivid capturing/paused state?

Tags: raspivid

raspivid has these options to cycle between capture and pause:

```
-s, --signal    : Cycle between capture and pause on Signal
-k, --keypress  : Cycle between capture and pause on ENTER
```

Suppose I use the `-k` option. After pressing Enter a number of times, I lose count. So how do I tell whether raspivid is now capturing or paused? I *could* monitor the file size of the output file, but that feels a bit dirty, especially if I also use the `-sg` option to segment the recordings.

Comment: I haven't used this option before and I don't have a Pi next to me right this second. The [docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md) say that adding the verbose option, -v, displays a prompt for user input during keypress mode (-k). I don't know what'll be in the prompt. Could you test it?

Comment: @goobering The `-v` option indeed adds status update messages to the console output. Very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments below the question, when raspivid is started using both the keypress option (`-k`) and the verbose option (`-v`), the user is provided with an on-screen prompt which allows the user to distinguish between capturing/not capturing modes.